# Run commands in tmux from terminal

Tags: tmux

I want to run some commands in `tmux` when I launch tmux from `gnome-terminal`

Something like

```
$ tmux run "command 1" in first panel \
and "command 3" in a vertically split second panel ;
```

It performs as follows :

1. It opens `tmux` and runs `command 1` in the first panel
2. And then opens new vertical split panel and runs `command 2` in it without waiting for `command 1` to complete (i.e `command 1` is still not running in first panel)

How can I do it ?

I do not want this to add this to my `~/.tmux.conf` as I don't want this to run every time I open `tmux`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
tmux new "echo hello; sleep 10" ';' split "echo world; sleep 10"
```

This will create a new `tmux` "window" which runs the first command, then this is split vertically to create a new pane in which the second command is run. The two commands will be started nearly concurrently.  Without the `sleep`, the `tmux` window will disappear just after the `echo`'s are done.

The `';'` delimits the two `tmux` commands `new` (`new-window`) and `split` (`split-window`). This has to be protected from the shell by escaping or quoting.

To split in the other orientation, use `split -h`.

Comment: Thanks, but it disappears after 10 seconds, I want it to stay until I exit tmux.

Comment: `tmux` will exit when all managed commands have exited. This is by design. You would have to tag on something like `bash` instead of `sleep 10` to get an interactive session started after the commands have executed. The `tmux` session will end when all those `bash` sessions have finished.

Comment: To execute a command and continue to use the shell after, I've used the `--init-file` flag like this: `split "bash --init-file <(echo 'echo hello world;')"`